# Adding a menu inside of a menubutton? Python

Tags: python-3.x, menu, tkinter

I am trying to create a menubutton with menus in it, and am unable to find anything within tkinter's documentation, did I miss it, or is it not possible? Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a menu and nest further menu's inside one another. Here's the link to the relevant [documentation](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/menu.htm)

A small example of nested menus like in your question.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

menubar = Menu(root)

helpmenu = Menu(menubar)
nested_menu1 = Menu(helpmenu)
nested_menu1.add_command(label='Stuff 1')
nested_menu1.add_command(label='Stuff 2')

nested_menu2 = Menu(helpmenu)
nested_menu2.add_command(label='Stuff 3')
nested_menu2.add_command(label='Stuff 4')

menu2_nested = Menu(nested_menu2)
menu2_nested.add_command(label='Stuff 5')
nested_menu2.add_cascade(label='Nestception', menu=menu2_nested)

helpmenu.add_cascade(label='1.0 Nested', menu=nested_menu1)
helpmenu.add_cascade(label='2.0 Nested', menu=nested_menu2)

menubar.add_cascade(label="Nested Menus", menu=helpmenu)

root.config(menu=menubar)
root.mainloop()
```

You can then add more panels to the horizontal menu by repeating the process for helpmenu and then you can have either one menu option with further dropdown menus or a whole row of these and of course you can nest as much as you like.

You can even put these menu's inside of your `menubutton`, or you could nest further menubutton's, and place them anywhere in your layout:

```
from tkinter import *

top = Tk()

for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):

        mb=  Menubutton(top, text="Menu 1")
        mb.menu  =  Menu(mb)
        mb["menu"]  =  mb.menu

        helpmenu = Menu(mb.menu)
        nested_menu1 = Menu(helpmenu)
        nested_menu1.add_command(label='Stuff 1')
        nested_menu1.add_command(label='Stuff 2')

        nested_menu2 = Menu(helpmenu)
        nested_menu2.add_command(label='Stuff 3')
        nested_menu2.add_command(label='Stuff 4')

        menu2_nested = Menu(nested_menu2)
        menu2_nested.add_command(label='Stuff 5')
        nested_menu2.add_cascade(label='Nestception', menu=menu2_nested)

        helpmenu.add_cascade(label='1.0 Nested', menu=nested_menu1)
        helpmenu.add_cascade(label='2.0 Nested', menu=nested_menu2)

        mb.menu.add_cascade(label="Nested Menus", menu=helpmenu)
        mb.grid(row=i, column=j)

top.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this is not quite what I was asking, I am trying to nest a menu within a menubutton, not a menu within a menu.

Comment: I should probably provide an example of code, I will be able to do this when I finish lectures today, so about 4 hours from now.